# Search for a specific section/paragraph in text from large amount of unstructured text data

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, chatbot

I am working on a project where given hundreds of word documents with largely unstructured text (mainly paragraphs and some bold headers here and there), develop a search engine/chatbot that when you search for something (how do i do X or Y), it will search through all of the documents and return the paragraph or section from the document that is relevant back to the user in text.

These documents are basically manuals which have instructions on how to perform specific tasks, they are all a few pages long. Problem is, the formatting is not uniform so different documents might be formatted slightly differently.

Sort of like building a question-and-answer bot, but the documents don't have any Q or A fields. Was thinking of using Elasticsearch to index all of the documents as a start, but not really sure how to go about the actual search part, or just how how I should go about doing this in general. Any ideas or pointers are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One idea to try: index each paragraph as a document in ElasticSearch.  Something like this:

```
{
    "book": "title here",
    "pageNumber": 123,
    "chapter": 7,
    "chapterTitle": "chapter title here",
    "paragraph": "put it here"
}
```

This would give you the ability to search paragraphs for what you want and return what page and book and chapter it occurred on.

I would NOT index the whole book in a single document, that will be super hard for ES to search effectively.

Comment: Is there a way for Elasticsearch to automatically index all of the paragraphs as separate documents? Or would I have to go manually through all of them and add them in.

Comment: Manually. ES is not specifically a "book indexing engine" so you'll have to do a good but if work on your own